# Spring with Ratpack and Actuator

Tags: spring, spring-boot-actuator, spring-web, ratpack

I am building some apis with Spring and Ratpack, using the whole Spring boot and cloud and Ratpack only for http and async-related-stuff.

My current problem is the usage of this stack with Actuator.
Because since I am running Ratpack and disabling spring webmvc, looks like it disables Actuator as well:

```
SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(Application.class);
application.setWebEnvironment(false);
application.setBannerMode(Banner.Mode.OFF);
application.run(args);
```

This is in fact the problem, because if I set web environment to true and tell ratpack to run on yet another port, it works, but I do not want to have three servers running for this, right?

Thank you guys for any support!